# .desktop invoking perl and terminal blinks on and off without running; yet runs fine using EXEC line in terminal

Tags: scripts, launcher, .desktop, perl, lxterminal

My problem is getting a .desktop file that runs a script with parameter(s) in a terminal to stay open rather than blink on and off, presumably taking with it the error messages I need.

I show some simple scripts and .desktops to demonstrate that it should work.

```
$ cat /home/westmj/GoogleDrive/perl/hello_world.pl
 #! /usr/bin/perl
 print "Hello, World!\n\@ARGV:\n";
 foreach $arg (@ARGV) {
    print "$arg\n";
}
warn "Press 'Enter' or 'Return' to finish.\n";
<STDIN>

$ /usr/bin/perl /home/westmj/GoogleDrive/perl/hello_world.pl 1 a.txt
```

Hello, World!
@ARGV:
1
a.txt
Press 'Enter' or 'Return' to finish.

```
$ cat hello_world_desktop.desktop
#
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Hello_World_desktop
Comment=Execute by dropping file onto
Exec=/usr/bin/perl /home/westmj/GoogleDrive/perl/hello_world.pl '%F'
Terminal=true
Type=Application
MimeType=application/vnd.ms-excel;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;inode/directory;text/plain;text/x-script.perl;
```

When the file a.txt is dropped on hello_world_desktop.desktop, a terminal opens with the output shown (note the fullpathname), and waits for a return to be dismissed as before.

Hello, World!
@ARGV:
/home/westmj/GoogleDrive/perl/a.txt
Press 'Enter' or 'Return' to finish.

Now the fun begins.  I have a more complex script, but it runs at the command line and takes a filename parameter successfully, and patiently waits to be dismissed.

```
$ /usr/bin/perl /home/westmj/GoogleDrive/perl/attenders.pl /home/westmj/GoogleDrive/perl/Attenders_database.xls
```

Input database found in /home/westmj/GoogleDrive/perl/Attenders_database.xls
Made copy of
/home/westmj/GoogleDrive/perl/Attenders_database.xls as
    /home/westmj/GoogleDrive/perl/ -
    2016_08_Aug_11_/home/westmj/GoogleDrive/perl/Attenders_database.xls
    to maintain database history.
Database Version 'August 11, 2016' File suffix '2016_08_Aug_11'
Output directory = /home/westmj/GoogleDrive/perl/

Done with creation of reports.

Press 'Enter' or 'Return' to exit.

And I have a .desktop file that should be using the same invoking:

```
$ cat attenders_desktop_04.desktop
 #
 [Desktop Entry]
 Version=1.0
 Name=attenders_desktop_04
 Comment=Drag and drop onto this the Attenders_database.xls[x] and optionally directory for output
 Exec=/usr/bin/perl /home/westmj/GoogleDrive/perl/attenders.pl '%F'
 Terminal=true
 Type=Application
 MimeType=application/vnd.ms-excel;application/vnd.ms-office;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;inode/directory;application/zip;
```

But if I drag Attenders_database.xls onto attenders_desktop_04.desktop, all that happens is a terminal briefly opens and closes.

I do not think it is a matter of permissions.

```
$ ls -la *.desktop
-rwxrw-r-- 1 westmj westmj 411 Sep 16 21:55 attenders_desktop_04.desktop
-rwxrw-r-- 1 westmj westmj 340 Sep 16 21:52 hello_world_desktop.desktop
```

What now?  Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Your question is related to this one: http://askubuntu.com/q/744658/295286  Basic idea is that `.desktop` files flash because they wait for a window to appear. If script doesn't show a window, it keeps flashing until it times out. Also, note that `.desktop` files for  scripts *do not* automatically bring up terminal window. You need to call them manually.  Or use my answer here, to launch scripts with terminal window from file manager http://askubuntu.com/a/822874/295286